# Is there any way we can prevent startup items in Windows 10 from being modified and/or deleted by using bootable media?

Tags: windows-10

If we would like to start programs, scripts or similar at the startup of Windows, there are several ways to achieve this using the registry and the file manager. But there are also ways to modify or delete these entries without even booting Windows. An unauthorized user may for instance boot a mini recovery operating system or even Windows' own disk installer from a USB drive, and then access the registry, CMD or the file manager to make the necessary changes to modify and/or delete startup items. My question is: **is there any way we can prevent startup items in Windows 10 from being modified and/or deleted by using bootable media?**

I know that the chances are small, they most likely do not even exist, but this would be extremely useful, as far as security is concerned. This would allow only the owner of a Windows computer to modify said entries, which means security measures may be undertaken to restrict certain users I have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to mitigate the risk, but there are no ways to remove it entirely. This is why physical security is as important as digital security.

To mitigate risk:

- make sure your computers have a TPM (Trusted Platform Module) and the hard disk is fully encrypted.
- set passwords on your BIOS and prevent changing the boot settings.
- disable USB ports in the BIOS if you can.
- physically lock the computer inside cabinets.

Outside these methods you must always assume that if the machine is physically compromised, it is digitally compromised too.

If your computer does not have TPM, set up BitLocker to require a physical USB key to decrypt the drive, and keep this USB key with you at all times. The computer will not be able to boot nor will the drive be able to be decrypted without that USB key.

*(Well, it is possible to decrypt an encrypted drive without the key, but it is very difficult and requires super-computer-levels of compute power. It's not perfect security, but it is one significant part of good security.)*

Comment: Thank you for a quick and accurate answer.

- It does not seem like my computer, which is five years old, supports TPM. Is BitLocker enough encryption?
- I have already set a BIOS password and I do not really need to change any boot settings.
- It does not seem like my computer supports disabling of USB ports.
- This is a laptop, so I am afraid I am not able to do so. I use it on the go and if I leave it, it is only for a couple of hours at most.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your lack of TPM.

Comment: I also tried to use BitLocker to encrypt the C-drive and require a USB drive to decrypt it on startup. The problem here is that the USB drive can be cloned by anyone who somehow gets a hold of it. It would be better if Windows generated a new encryption key on each startup.

Comment: We've already discussed physical security. Your security will be as good as your keeping that key safe, and you keeping the key with your personally means the data on your drive is essentially unreadable when you're not around. Also, since you don't have a TPM, you will need to hold that password somewhere/somehow.

Comment: Well, I already knew this and had even tested the different physical solutions. So the answer to my question is no?

Comment: Correct. BitLocker does not generate new keys each boot. If it did it would have to decrypt and re-encrypt the drive each time, which is a very time-consuming process.

Comment: Oh, then I understand that part. It is actually logical. But my main question of the topic?

Comment: That has been answered in my original answer. Security is risk mitigation, not prevention, and the way to mitigate the risks you have described are through the specific points I have already noted.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time. I appreciate that people like you spend time providing thorough, useful answers and advice.

Answer (score -1):

That's a Good Question,

You can lock your BIOS or CMOS Setup With password so if Any one tries to enter your BIOS or even try to Boot from an another device by pressing F12 in the start up, he will be asked for the password and that will stop him, But if he is a Professional One this wont stop him because there is some tricks to bypass it, at least you Semi-Protected your Computer.

Let me tell you something, Keep your Computer with you all the Time, That's All.

And Like you Said "the chances are small", Don't let it Kill you for the same instant when the unauthorized user boot a mini recovery operating system, Take Care.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and accurate answer. I have already set a BIOS password, but I am looking for more security - as you said, this can easily be bypassed by anyone with a bit knowledge about reseting BIOS passwords or otherwise bypass this security measure.

Comment: @MohamedElTagoury No, that's absolutely false. UNIX operating systems are just as vulnerable to physical attacks as any other operating system.